# How to do classification with K-means

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm new to clustering and K-means algorithm and I would like to classify some sentences into 2 clusters. If i have the below  sentences :

```
 sentences =  ["I didn't enjoyed the film", "the weather is nice", "The food was great last night", "our dog if very friendly"]
```

How can i cluster them into 2 clusters using kmeans? i know I have to use `model = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=2,random_state=42)` but i do not know how can i make the sentences good to be appied KMeans on them. Also how can i print at the end, the sentence and the cluster number it belongs to? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: KMean clustering takes points in your space. Since you want to cluster sentences you'll have to convert them to points, there are many ways to do it, when you do it just take your points and fit the clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The K-means algorithm works on numerical data so the key step when processing text is to convert the text into a numerical representation that can be used to cluster upon.

There are many ways to represent text as numbers (from simple word counts to complex algorithms) and the choice will depend your time and experience.

The simple steps are:

- Text preprocessing (get rid of bad characters)
- Text vectorisation (turn text into numbers)
- Classification (your K-means step)

I recommend looking into a tutorial as there are lots steps leading up to the clustering that will have a large impact on your results, such as text cleaning and vectorisation that will be better delivered in depth.

If you want to see it done quickly.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

sentences =  ["I didn't enjoyed the film", "the weather is nice", "The food was great last night", "our dog if very friendly"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
km.fit(X)
print(list(zip(sentences, km.labels_)))
```

This will cluster but, given the low number of words, it probably doesn't show anything interesting.